# YouTube Data API: The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota. Сan I make an app using the YouTube Data API or not?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

I got this error:

> The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).

and I can not understand YouTube limits the number of requests? That is, I cannot create my project by taking API from my channel? If this is so, what is the point of YouTube Data API, if at the development stage I was already limited, what will happen when users come in, then my project will fall within 5 minutes?

[image]

and I cannot understand how I was able to make 10,000 requests per day, given that I worked on the `localhost` for about 3 hours, is this possible?

[image]
[image]

Comment: As  stavar has already stated, I don't think you completely understand the YouTube Cost based quota.   This video might help as well https://youtu.be/MHUGuw1Agnc.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the Google's Developers Console shows text like *Queries per day*, but that's very much misleading (and may well be reported as an Web UI bug to Google).

You have to acknowledge that *YouTube Data API's [quota system](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) is not accounting for the number of endpoints calls* you made during a day long, but *it accounts for the cumulated number of quota units corresponding to each of your endpoint calls*.

For example, if you have 10000 units of quota allocated for daily usage, you may very easily exceed this upper bound after only 100 calls to the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint.

Many API users find the default amount of quota allocated -- 10000 units -- to be quite constraining -- that even during the development stage of their apps. For tackling this issue, I recommend two things:

- Develop your app such that to cache API responses it received from the endpoints it calls; this way, during the development stage of your app (afterwards, even during production, but albeit functioning with a different logic), repeated calls to endpoints would not result in actual API requests, but would get served from the app's local cache.
- Apply for a quota extension, using Google's [official form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form); be aware that, as per the experience of users of this forum, Google's answer, usually, does not arrive shortly.

Comment: Any chance we can come up with a single question to duplicate all of these to it seems we answer this same question all the time.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. In my opinion, the Console itself is the foremost culprit; then the API docs -- the [Guides section](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) -- could be more explicit about these things, having a dedicated page. On the other hand, new users may find quite appealing to have a video explaining these things (I know you started a developers oriented channel). The only real issue is that helping *concretely* Google API users is somewhat difficult due to the multitude of programming languages/environments implied.

Comment: This is getting to chatty.  Ping me on twitter sometime. I would love to chat with another Api addict.

Comment: and what will happen when I put my site on the Internet? users will come to it and will it also be limited by the number of quotas?